# Creating a list of booleans on the fly

Tags: java, design-patterns, data-structures, language-agnostic, boolean

Imagine we are pulling data about people and their favourite foods.
The data would come to us in the format: "Name, FavFood<sub>1</sub>, FavFood<sub>2</sub>..FavFood<sub>n</sub>".
e.g. "James, Beans, Chicken".
Notice how we do not know how many foods a person will favour.
From this data we create an instance of a **Person** object which captures the person's name and favourite foods. 
After we have pulled data on every person, we want to create a spreadsheet whose columns would be: `Name|Potato|Chicken|Beans|Curry` etc.
All of the values to the right of the person's name will be simple boolean values representing whether or not that food was one of the person's favourites.
***The problem is:*** we do not know in advance; all the foods that someone could possibly favour, and as such cannot just set up boolean instance variables in the **Person** class.
I've given this some thought, implementing sets,hash-sets and hash-maps, however every solution I think of ends up being horribly inelegant and so I've turned to the genius of stackoverflow for help on this one.
***My question is:*** What design pattern / approach can I use to cleanly achieve the outcome I desire?
 Whilst this is a language-agnostic question I am programming this in Java, so if there's anything in the Java API or elsewhere built for this, do let me know.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why is `HashMap` a horribly inelegant solution?

Comment: What don't you like in using sets as a collection of all foods, a set of person?
I would think about having the data itself (e.g. a set of persons, where each person has its set of favourite foods) and a projection of that data - it doesn't even have to be a data type but just a mechanism of mapping that data to a UI component you have.

Comment: Did you try anything already? Does it work? If not, what doesn't work? Do you get an error?

Comment: Maybe you could post an "inelegant" example of using sets for each person and a global set of all the food seen so far, explain what is so inelegant about it, and then we can get it to be more elegant?

Comment: @SergeyTachenov Not only is the solution not elegant in my view but it's also not concrete, and to avoid posting an XY problem I posted my question as it is.

Comment: @PiotrekBzdyl could you explain that further please? Because I can't see how that approach would allow me to end up with the booleans for each food item, for each person.

Comment: @quantum285 My point about the design is to separate your business domain model from the presentation/view model. I don't know your context, but in case of a system which tracks people's food preferences, your Person and their favourite foods is your domain model. Another topic is your presentation model (you can have more than one depending on requirements) that works as a particular view of your domain model data (text tables, GUI spreadsheet, HTML page etc.) This gives you decoupling and flexibility in implementing multiple view types and not mixing their logic into the domain model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It generates data in csv form.

```
class Person {
  final String name;
  final Set<String> foods;

  Person(String name, Set<String> foods) {
    this.name = name;
    this.foods = foods;
  }

  Stream<Boolean> getBooleans(List<String> foods) {
    return foods.stream().map(food -> this.foods.contains(food));
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Person(" + name + ", " + foods +")";
  }
}

class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> data = Arrays.asList(
      "James, Beans, Chicken",
      "Emily, Potato, Curry",
      "Clara, Beans, Curry"
    );

    List<String> foodNames = Arrays.asList(
      "Potato", "Chicken", "Beans", "Curry"
    );

    Stream<Person> persons = data.stream().map(d -> {
      String[] split = d.split(",");
      for(int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        split[i] = split[i].trim();
      }
      String name = split[0];
      Set<String> foods = Stream.of(split).skip(1).collect(Collectors.toSet());
      return new Person(name, foods);
    });

    Stream<String> csvData = persons.map(p ->
      p.name + ", " + p.getBooleans(foodNames)
        .map(b -> b.toString())
        .collect(Collectors.joining(", "))
    );
    csvData.forEach(System.out::println);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks promising; I need to learn about Streams. Do you mind checking the assignment of csvData? It's bringing up an error flag and sticking in a "}" hasn't helped ha.

Comment: *Sticking in curly braces

Comment: Sorry, there was a `;` missing

Answer (score 1):

What is so inelegant about this pseudocode?

```
Set<String> allFoods = new TreeSet<String>();
List<Person> allPersons = new ArrayList<Person>();
while (hasMorePersons()) {
    Person person = getNextPerson();
    allPersons.add(person);
    allFoods.addAll(person.getFoods());
}
spreadSheet.writeHeader("Name", allFoods);
for (Person person : allPersons) {
    spreadSheet.writeName(person.getName());
    for (String food : allFoods) {
        // assume getFoods() return a Set<String>,
        // not necessarily ordered (could be a HashSet)
        boolean yourBooleanHere = person.getFoods().contains(food);
        spreadSheet.writeBoolean(yourBooleanHere);
    }
    spreadSheet.nextLine();
}
```

If you need a table of booleans or whatever else, you can easily store them anywhere you want during the second loop.

Note: TreeSet orders foods according to the natural order (that is, alphabetically). To output them in the order they are encountered, use a `LinkedHashSet` instead.

Comment: Just to clarify: I never said HashMaps/ HashSets are inelegant, neither that any solution that uses them is. I said **my** solutions were inelegant. That said, this is awesome and just what I needed, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I highly recommend that whatever you do it in a separate class with methods like addFavoriteFood(String food) and boolean isFavoriteFood(String food) getFavorites(String food).

Personally I think the implementation of this class should contain both an instance HashSet (to hold the foods this person likes) and a SortedSet that is common to all the foods that can contain a list of ALL foods.  (See notes at end)

Add would add it to both sets, getFavorites would return those in the first Hash set.

Hmm, it may also need a static getAllFavorites() method to return the SortedSet

Since your FavoiteFoods class knows the master list AND the person's favorites, you could even have it do most of the work by having a getFormattedRow() and static getFormattedHeaderRow() method.  then your implementaiton is just:

```
System.out.println(FavoriteFoods.getFormattedHeaderRow());
for(Person person:people)
    System.out.println(person.favoriteFood.getFormattedRow());
```

Again, the best thing here is that you can just use the Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work for your implementation and re-do it later if need be since, being isolated in another class, it doesn't infect all your code with nasty implementation-specific sets, classes, booleans, etc.

Notes about the master list: This master list could naively be implemented as a Static but that's a bad idea--optimally the same masterList SortedSet would be passed into each instance on construction. Also since it is shared among all instances and is mutable it brings in issues if your solution is threaded!

Comment: I disagree with this usage of `static`. I'd rather add another containing class on top of the persons list, or maybe even extend from some existing collection, overriding `add()`. But static is global, and therefore generally bad.

Comment: I agree.  The master list should probably be passed to each list of foods as it is created, but it seemed to add more complexity to an answer that was already getting too long and I wanted to streamline it.  Perhaps that was a bad idea--I can add it as a note on the answer.